# How to batch insert to database when enough n records with Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, batch-updates

I have an activities log tables, And I want to batch write to log tables each time system collected more than 100 records.
How to do that with Laravel ?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you explain why you want to do it this way? Why not just insert them as they come in, one by one?

Comment: Hello @ceejayoz, I want to save write database cost & optimize performance for system.

Comment: This adds a lot of complexity and risk of lost records for minimal performance benefit. It's likely there are much better places to work on performance, and that this is premature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that as below...

```
$data = array(
array(
    'log_name'=>'Syntax',
    'type'=>'Error',
    'created_at'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'modified_at'=> date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
   ),
array(
     'log_name'=>'Logical',
     'type'=>'Warning',
     'created_at'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
     'modified_at'=> date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
   ),
//...
);
Log::insert($data);
```

Or using query builder as

```
DB::table('log')->insert($data);
```